# How might I write a program to extract my data from Google Code?

Tags: html, google-code

I'm about to start writing a program which will attempt to extract data from a [Google Code site](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/) so that it may be imported in to another project management site. Specifically, I need to extract the full issue detail from the site (description, comments, and so on).

Unfortunately Google don't provide an API for this, nor do they have an export feature, so to me the only option looks to be extracting the data from the actual HTML (yuck). Does any one have any suggestions on "best practice" from attempting to parse data out of HTML? I'm aware that this is less than ideal, but I don't think I have much choice. Can anyone else think of a better way, or maybe someone else has already done this?

Also, I'm aware of the CSV export feature on the issue page, however this does not give complete data about issues (but could be a useful starting point).

Comment: You should edit your question and specify exactly which data you are trying to extract from google code. The issues? The wiki? etc. Answers will vary ...

Comment: Ah, you're right. Issues, specifically, since it's the only data that you can't easily extract by hand.

Comment: 'tis a known limitation: http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_get_a_copy_of_my_data%3f which given Google's strong interest in not locking you into their service, wouldn't surprise me if it came sooner rather than later.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't trust Google to introduce new major features any time soon, given that Google Code doesn't make them any proffit.

Comment: Google has a very idiosyncratic (and broad) definition of "profit". They also have teams that exist only to enhance and proselytize their own domain. (Then again, I wouldn't hold my breath whilst waiting).

Comment: I agree, but I don't think it's too far fetched to imagine that GC was just a publicity stunt to show that Google cares about open source. Now that it's served it's purpose, it seems to have been a little neglected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just finished a program called [google-code-export](http://github.com/nbolton/google-code-export) (hosted on Github). This allows you to export your Google Code project to an XML file, for example:

```
>main.py -p synergy-plus -s 1 -c 1
parse: http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=1
wrote: synergy-plus_google-code-export.xml
```

... will create a file named [synergy-plus_google-code-export.xml](http://pastebin.com/bTrnks6P).